# How do you convert UTF8 number into written text

Tags: c#, utf-8

I am writing a winform to convert written text into *Unicode* numbers and *UTF8* numbers. This bit is working well

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Convert to UTF8
        // The return will be either 1 byte, 2 bytes or 3 bytes.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        string utext = rchtxbx_text.Text;

        // do one char at a time
        for (int text_index = 0; text_index < utext.Length; text_index++) 
        {
            byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(utext.Substring(text_index, 1));

            for (int index = 0; index < encodedBytes.Length; index++)

            {
                builder.AppendFormat("{0}", Convert.ToString(encodedBytes[index], 16));
            }

            builder.Append(" ");
        }

        rchtxtbx_UTF8.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("San Serif", 20);
        rchtxtbx_UTF8.AppendText(builder.ToString() + "\r");
```

As an example the characters 乘义ש give me e4b998 e4b989 d7a9, note I have a mix LtoR and RtoL text. Now if the user inputs the number  **e4b998** I want to show them it is **乘**, in Unicode 4E58

I have tried a few things and the closest I got, but still far away, is

```
   Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
   rchtxbx_text.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(utf8.GetBytes(e4b998));
```

What do I need to do to input **e4b998** and write **乘** to a textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

1. Split `source` into 2-character chunks: `"e4b998"` -> `{"e4", "b9", "98"}`
2. `Convert` chunks into bytes
3. `Encode` bytes into the final string

Implementation:

```
  string source = "e4b998";

  string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Enumerable
    .Range(0, source.Length / 2)
    .Select(i => Convert.ToByte(source.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16))
    .ToArray());
```

If you have an `int` as `source`:

Answer (score 0):

```
string s_unicode2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8.GetBytes(e4b998));
```

Comment: That was one of the things I tried but inputting e4b998 from a text box results in an output to a box of the same e4b998. If it was Unicode I would know they are all 2 bytes but in UTF8 they can be 1 or 2 or 3 bytes. How does the system know which is which from the string e4b998e4b989d7a9?